# Where is data being persisted to with Psycopg2?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have postgres running on my local machine and i am accessing it through command line. I have a python script that I am using to read in data and persist it to my postgres database using psycopg2. My python exemplar code is as follows:

```
 try:
     connection = psycopg2.connect(user = "<username>",
                              password = "<password>",
                              host = "localhost",
                              port = "5432",
                              database = "<databasename>")

cursor = connection.cursor()

create_table_query = '''CREATE TABLE mobile
      (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
      MODEL           TEXT    NOT NULL,
      PRICE         REAL); '''

cursor.execute(create_table_query)
connection.commit()
print("Table created successfully in PostgreSQL ")

 except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error :
     print ("Error while creating PostgreSQL table", error)
 finally:
     #closing database connection.
          if(connection):
             cursor.close()
             connection.close()
             print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

This all runs fine and when I do a `.fetchall()` in my python script it brings batch the data from the table, but when I try that same command in my postgres command line I get the following:

[image]

What is the missing link here to persist my data locally?

Comment: You need to do `\c<databasename>` to connect to the correct database in the psql console.  Your psql is currently connected to the `postgres` database.

Comment: wow that was a very silly oversight on my part, thank you!!